# Many-To-Many Bidirectional relationships with Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have got a many-to-many bidirectional relationship in Doctrine. It associates items with categories. The issue is that at the beginning I am assigning a category to a item correctly, but when I am trying to update an item's category then it fails, with a duplicate primary key.

These are some snippets from the code that might be helpful:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="item")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SomeBundle\Entity\Repository\ItemRepository")
 *
 */
class Item
{
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="items",   cascade={"persist"})
     **/
    private $categories;
 public function __construct()
    {
        $this->categories = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
/**
     * @param Item $item
     */
    public function addItem(Item $item)
    {
        $this->items[] = $item;
    }
```

and

```
/**
 * Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="category", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="category_parent", columns={"parent_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SomeBundle\Entity\Repository\CategoryRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Item", mappedBy="categories", cascade={"persist"})
    * @ORM\JoinTable(name="item_category")
    **/
    private $items;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->items = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @param Category $category
     */
    public function addCategory(Category $category)
    {
        $this->categories[] = $category;
        $category->addItem($this);
    }
```

**UPDATE**

```
 public function saveItem(Request $request)
    {
        $editMode = false;
        $itemId = $request->request->get('item_id');

        if (isset($itemId) && $itemId > 0) {
            $editMode = true;
        }

        $itemName = $request->request->get('itemName');
        $itemShortName= $request->request->get('itemShortName');

        $itemRepo = $this->getItemRepository();
        $item = $itemRepo->find($itemId);

        // get last Item Id
        if (!$editMode) {
            $newItem = new Item();
            $newItemId = rand(1000, 6000); // TODO
            $newItem->setId($newItemId);
            $newItem->setSection('ar');
            // by default the item is inactive
            $newItem->setActive(0);
        }

        //store the Item Type
        $itemType = new ItemType();
        $itemType->setTypeId($request->request->get('itemType'));

        if (!$editMode) {
            $itemType->setItemId($newItemId);
        }

        // store the data into the ItemTranslation
        if (!$editMode) {
            $newItemTranslation = new ItemTranslation();
            $newItemTranslation->setItemId($newItemId);
            $newItemTranslation->setLanguageId('1');
            $newItemTranslation->setItemName($itemName);
            $newItemTranslation->ItemShortname($itemShortName);
            $newItemTranslation->setTimestampAdd(new \DateTime());
            $this->em->persist($newItemTranslation);
        }

        //assign the respective Categories to the item
        $selectedCategoriesIds = $request->request->get('itemCategories');
        $categoryRepo = $this->getCategoryRepository();

        if (count($selectedCategoriesIds) > 0) {
            foreach ($selectedCategoriesIds as $selectedCategoryId) {
                $category = $categoryRepo->find($selectedCategoryId);
                if (is_object($item)) { //TODO
                    $item->addCategory($category);
                    $category->addItem($item);

                } else {
                    $newItem->addCategory($category);
                    $category->addItem($newItem);
                }

                if (!$editMode) {
                    $this->em->persist($newItem);
                }
            }
        }

        $this->em->flush();
    }
```

**Error Message**

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO item_category (item_id, category_id) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [2117, 1]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '2117-1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

** SECOND UPDATE **

I have added this
     if (is_object($item)) {
                $item->removeExistingCategories();
            }
just before:

```
if (count($selectedCategoriesIds) > 0) {
            foreach ($selectedCategoriesIds as $selectedCategoryId) {
                $category = $categoryRepo->find($selectedCategoryId);
```

and it seems that it works fine, with the exception that now the categories are being appeared twice in the UI, although the ***item_category*** table has been correctly populated.

OK, the last issue seems to have been sorted. I have made a mistake in itemsCategories iteration. :)

Comment: We might need to see the Controller (or elsewhere the problem occurs). What do you mean exactly by `update an item's category`?

Comment: @caCtus Thanks for the reply. I mean that I may want to update the categories that an item belongs to.

Comment: Could you add the error message? I assume you have a duplicate line in `item_category` join table but just to be sure I am looking at the right issue. :)

Comment: In your `//TODO` `if` statement, you add the category to the item, even if this item already had this category. (Maybe you already knew it but in case. ^^) Here you might check if the item already have the category before adding it, OR first remove all your item categories and then add all the categories you want. It is not the best way to do it though, you should have used [Symfony form builders](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#building-the-form), it does things itself without much code to write.

Comment: @caCtus Interesting suggestion about the Symfony form builders. 
To answer your first hypothesis, I was expecting from doctrine to be smart enough to just update the categories that an item belongs to, automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing cascade persist on Category Entity...you should do that only on the owning side of the relationship (Item in your case).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Stev.
I removed it as suggested, and now I am getting the same error when I am trying to keep the same category and add a new one to the item. 
But, when I remove the pre-existing category and add the item into another category, then the old one is not deleted but the new one is stored properly.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Read this article http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html.
Especially the part with Doctrine Persistence from the end.